# How to filter NeoModel Nodes by Relationships in Python

Tags: python, django, neo4j, cypher, neomodel

I have the 2 StructuredNodes `User` and `Token` as a one to one relationship.
Coming from using Django for relational databases, if I want to get the User given a token, I'd simply do `User.objects.get(token__key=token)`.

But using Neo4j with NeoModel, I'm struggling to find a way to do this simple query. Do I have to use cypher for this? if so how?

Also, when I have the `User` instance, I can do `user.token.single()` to get the `Token` instance, but the same doesn't work the other way around. `token.user.single()` returns `CardinalityViolation: Expected: one relationship in a outgoing direction of type FOR_USER on node (49) of class 'Token', got: none.` and token.user returns a `neomodel.cardinality.One` object.

```
class User(DjangoNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    firstname = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    lastname = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    email = EmailProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)
    password = StringProperty(requried=True)

    token = RelationshipFrom('Token', 'OWNS_TOKEN', cardinality=One)

    def post_create(self):
        token = Token().save()
        self.token.connect(token)

class Token(DjangoNode):
    user = RelationshipTo('Token', 'FOR_USER', cardinality=One)

    key = StringProperty(unique_index=True, default=generate_key)
    created = DateTimeProperty(default_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit late for the answer but,

Shot in the dark here, but your RelationshipTo in your Token class is directed towards another Token, and not towards a specific user.